# PHP Combine fields in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Forgive my explanation of this as I am not a developer.

I have a query from php that produces the last five results from a teams matches.  I would like to display the outcome of those matches within another array.

I have the following

```
$_teams_form = $this->getFormResults($t['team']);

$team['form'] = $_teams_form[0]['form_result'].' '.$_teams_form[1]['form_result'].' '.$_teams_form[2]['form_result'].' '.$_teams_form[3]['form_result'].' '.$_teams_form[4]['form_result'];
```

This works and I can use the $team['form'] to display my data.  But I know the number of the arrays as I am limiting the records to 5 but if I change that then the code breaks.  I also want to change what I display depending on the contents of the $_teams_form[0]['form_result'] fields.

There must be a better way to manipulate this but my mind has gone blank, appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry that should be query from mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't use plain `implode` on that array, you're just gonna have to do the loop yourself:

```
$_teams_form = $this->getFormResults($t['team']);
$len = count($_teams_form);
$team['form'] = '';
if($len > 0) // Make sure $_teams_form[0] exists
{
    $team['form'] .= $_teams_form[0]['form_result'];
    for($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++) // $i = 1 because we've got 0 already
    {
        $team['form'] .= ' '.$_teams_form[$i]['form_result'];
    }
}
```

However, the real question (to me) is: Why is a non-developer required to do this?

Comment: Because its my site and I try to do as much of the work as possible myself.

Comment: Then you're basically on your way to becoming a developer. :P

Comment: I wish, my full time job stops me knowing a lot of what I should.  I have done  a lot of the coding myself and really should know these things.  Have done a lot by using examples.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you have done there, in the for loop $form['form_result'] doesn't exist

Comment: Looks like the last edit got lost, that should have been `$_teams_form[$i]['form_result']`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much.
Check the form tab and the form in the table.
[link](http://www.nifootball.co.uk/leagues/tables/bsml-division-1/2014-2015)